# CollectionView.MoveCurrentToPosition(Int32) didn't move all field data to current position

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to use the method for the navigation when users enter a page number instead of using the arrows to bring the data to display from the page number entered. What is very strange is that all data in textboxes are correctly displayed in the dataview, however any data that is in dropdown are not.

```
 private void sectionNextPrevious_CountLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int _currentRowNumber = ((CtrlUltraNextPrevious)sender).CurrentRowNumber;
        int _rowCount = ((CtrlUltraNextPrevious)sender).RowCount;
        int _sectionIndex = Convert.ToInt32(((CtrlUltraNextPrevious)sender).Count.Text);

        if (_sectionIndex > _rowCount || _sectionIndex == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Section " + (_sectionIndex) + " does not exist.", "Navigate to Section", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            ((CtrlUltraNextPrevious)sender).Count.Text = _currentRowNumber.ToString();
            return;
        }

        _sectionCollectionView.MoveCurrentToPosition(_sectionIndex - 1);
        _visData.Sect = sectionNextPrevious.CurrentRowNumber;

        BuildingHelper.SetSectionBindings(_visData, sectionNextPrevious, TableName);
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you've provided enough code. Looking at that though. I see setsectionbindings. Kind of looks like you're doing some dynamic stuff with bindings. That's odd. Is that perhaps set up the dropdownlist you mention? You've provided no code or markup for this.  A dataview is a view of a datatable. It doesn't actually display anything. So I'm not sure how a dataview is involved.

Comment: _sectionCollectionView was correct before the line  _sectionCollectionView.MoveCurrentToPosition(_sectionIndex - 1). The dataview is not correct anymore after the line with the dropdown fields data all replaced with the data from the the row that's is entered. It went wrong before the binding line.